# What is the macro below doing in regards to dates (months) . Is it setting time period to one month and which month each time?

Tags: date, macros, sas

I am counting number of rows using static dates (e.g. datefield >=01/02/2019 and datefield<= 28/02/2019) and i get x number of rows.My report is to run monthly

An automated report developed by someone else defines time period (should be one month) defines time period with macro below. And for the same time period that report gives y number of rows.

Could someone explain what the macro below is doing in plain english (needless to say my sas and proc sql skills are very limited)

I am assuming that it probably selects more than one months and hence the difference in numbers when i am counting rows

```
/*%macro (today = );*/
option MPRINT MLOGIC symbolgen;

data _null_;
M_month =  month(&today);
if M_month in (1 2 3 4 5 6) then
        call symput('M_StartDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,-2-M_month,'beginning'), date9.));
else
        call symput('M_StartDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,4-M_month,'beginning'), date9.));


if M_month in ( 5 6)then
        call symput('M_EndDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,3-M_month,'end'), date9.));
else  if  M_month in ( 11 12) then
        call symput('M_EndDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,9-M_month,'end'), date9.));
else
        call symput('M_EndDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,-1,'end'), date9.));


call symput('M_CuttOffDate', put(intnx('month', &today , -1,'end'), date9.));


 call symput('run_MMMYY', put(intnx('month', &today , 0,'end'), EURDFMY5.));


run;
```

Comment: That is not a MACRO.  It is a data step (data \_null_ step) that is creating some macro variables.  So what is the question?

Comment: thanks! so the question remains what is the time period selected each time this monthly report runs? Is it the previous month? or is it the previous 6 months? I am trying to figure out the time period selected each time this data step runs .

Comment: so the question remains what is the time period selected each time this monthly report runs? Is it the previous month? or is it the previous 6 months? I am trying to figure out the time period selected each time this data step runs . –

Answer (score 1):

The last two are simple. Cuttoff is the last day of the previous month. The last MMMYY is just the current month in that format.

For the other two it is adjusting how much to change the date based on the month of the year.

To figure it out you might want to just make yourself a little truth table with one row per month of the year and columns for the different target macro variables.  So perhaps just write down the month of TODAY and then what month will be generated for the new macro variables.

```
data _null_;
do m_month=1 to 12 ;
  today = mdy(m_month,1,2018);
  if M_month in (1 2 3 4 5 6) then M_StartDate = intnx('month', today ,-2-M_month,'b');
  else M_StartDate = intnx('month', &today ,4-M_month,'b');

  if M_month in ( 5 6)then M_EndDate = intnx('month', today ,3-M_month,'e');
  else if  M_month in ( 11 12) then M_EndDate = intnx('month', today ,9-M_month,'e');
  else M_EndDate = intnx('month', today ,-1,'end');

  put (today m_startdate m_enddate) (=yymmdd10.);
end;
run;
```

Result

```
today=2018-01-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2017-12-31
today=2018-02-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2018-01-31
today=2018-03-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2018-02-28
today=2018-04-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2018-03-31
today=2018-05-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2018-03-31
today=2018-06-01 M_StartDate=2017-10-01 M_EndDate=2018-03-31
today=2018-07-01 M_StartDate=2018-04-01 M_EndDate=2018-06-30
today=2018-08-01 M_StartDate=2018-03-01 M_EndDate=2018-07-31
today=2018-09-01 M_StartDate=2018-02-01 M_EndDate=2018-08-31
today=2018-10-01 M_StartDate=2018-01-01 M_EndDate=2018-09-30
today=2018-11-01 M_StartDate=2017-12-01 M_EndDate=2018-09-30
today=2018-12-01 M_StartDate=2017-11-01 M_EndDate=2018-09-30
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the call symput and create variables instead.

   ```
   call symput('M_StartDate', put(intnx('month', &today ,-2-M_month,'beginning'), date9.));
   ```

Becomes:

```
M_StartDate = put(intnx('month', &today ,-2-M_month,'beginning'), date9.);
```

2. Remove the &today to use a variable instead, today
3. Add a loop to loop through the dates to see the different ranges.

   ```
   data demo;


   do today='01Jan2019'd to '31Dec2019'd;
   M_month=month(today);

   if M_month in (1 2 3 4 5 6) then
       M_StartDate=put(intnx('month', today , -2-M_month, 'beginning'), date9.);
   else
       M_StartDate=put(intnx('month', today , 4-M_month, 'beginning'), date9.);

   if M_month in (5 6)then
       M_EndDate=put(intnx('month', today , 3-M_month, 'end'), date9.);
   else if M_month in (11 12) then
       M_EndDate=put(intnx('month', today , 9-M_month, 'end'), date9.);
   else
       M_EndDate=put(intnx('month', today , -1, 'end'), date9.);
   M_CuttOffDate=put(intnx('month', today , -1, 'end'), date9.);
   run_MMMYY=put(intnx('month', today , 0, 'end'), EURDFMY5.);
   output;
   end;
   run;
   ```

Then you can check the output and see what the ranges are and if they're what you expect. It looks to be a dynamic range that varies.

Comment: Many thanks! I will have a go and report back! :) Many thanks!